# Apache: ServerTokens and ServerSignature: security guidelines

Tags: security, apache-2.4

There are a lot of sites that suggest that the following options should be set to their most reticent levels:

```
# /etc/apapce2/conf-available/security.conf
ServerTokens Prod
ServerSignature Off
```

However the [Apache 2.4 docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servertokens) say:

> Setting ServerTokens to less than minimal is not recommended because it makes it more difficult to debug interoperational problems. Also note that disabling the Server: header does nothing at all to make your server more secure. The idea of "security through obscurity" is a myth and leads to a false sense of safety.

I'm inclined to side with the Apache developers, but would I be correct to do so? What exploits would I open myself up to if I broadcast my Apache version?

Answer (score 0):

It would make it easier for hackers to choose the correct parameters when they exploit you with zero day bugs.

Comment: You're not worth burning a zero-day on.

Comment: @womble How do you know? Anyhow, it's not unheard of that zero-day bugs might be used in automatic mass-hacking tools or worms as well. In that case, the Apache version might be all it needs to know in order to let it jump right into the shellcode's memory address.

Comment: Statistical probability.